# Bind dynamic textbox to jquery-ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am dynamically generating the textbox and also loading the data from the server using ajax. I would like to implement autocomplete using jquery-ui plugin but somehow it does not work for dynamic textbox

```
var url = "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>?r=product/getProduct";
    $.get(url,function(model){
    prodList = $.parseJSON(model);
});

msg = '<table><tr><td>Item</td></tr>';
for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++){
    msg = msg + '<tr>';
    msg = msg + '<td><input type="text" class="span5" id="Name_' + i + '" ></td>';
    msg = msg + '</tr>';
    $(  "#Name_" + i ).autocomplete({ source: prodList});
}
msg = msg + '</table>';
$('#form').html(msg);
```

However, the textbox autocomplete feature does not work. Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just realized my silly mistake.

```
function AutoComplete(rows)
{
    for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++){
       $( '#Name_' + i ).autocomplete({source: prodList });
    }
}
```

.......
  ........

```
var url = "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>?r=product/getProduct";
    $.get(url,function(model){
    prodList = $.parseJSON(model);
    AutoComplete(rows);
});

msg = '<table><tr><td>Item</td></tr>';
for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++){
    msg = msg + '<tr>';
    msg = msg + '<td><input type="text" class="span5" id="Name_' + i + '" ></td>';
    msg = msg + '</tr>';
}
msg = msg + '</table>';
$('#form').html(msg);
```

Now it works like a charm.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something similar this:

```
var url = "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>?r=product/getProduct";
$.get(url,function(model){
prodList = $.parseJSON(model);
});

function displayMsg(rows, callback){
msg = '<table><tr><td>Item</td></tr>';
for(var i=1;i<=rows;i++){
msg = msg + '<tr>';
msg = msg + '<td><input type="text" class="span5 autocmp" id="Name_' + i + '" ></td>';
msg = msg + '</tr>';
    }
msg = msg + '</table>';
$('#form').html(msg);
```

}

```
function setAutocmp(){
$( ".autocmp" ).autocomplete({ source: prodList;});
}

displayMsg(rows, function(){setAutocmp()});
```